# Making large substack more readable?

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

I have the following code:

```
\[\mathcal{I}(A,B) = \inf_{\substack{h : M\times I\rightarrow M\\
                             h(\cdot,t) \;homeomorphism\\
                            h(x,0) = x\;\forall\; x\in X\\
                                    h(A,1) = B  
                            }} \max_{x\in X} \text{len} \;h(x, \cdot)\]
```

But the conditions in my substack are very tiny with respect to the rest of the equation.

[image]

Is there a way to increase the size of just the text in the substack? Maybe the spacing as well?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`\substack` is a modified array definition using smaller fonts so you can use a full array (as in the second example) but it's hard to read and I'd consider a different layout as in the third example where the condition is pulled out of the display. multi-letter identifiers such as homomorphism should never be set in math italic.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}


\[\mathcal{I}(A,B) = \inf_{\substack{h : M\times I\rightarrow M\\
                             h(\cdot,t) \;\text{homeomorphism}\\
                            h(x,0) = x\;\forall\; x\in X\\
                                    h(A,1) = B  
                            }} \max_{x\in X} \text{len} \;h(x, \cdot)\]



\[\mathcal{I}(A,B) = \inf_{\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}h : M\times I\rightarrow M\\
                             h(\cdot,t) \;\text{homeomorphism}\\
                            h(x,0) = x\;\forall\; x\in X\\
                                    h(A,1) = B  
                            \end{array}} \max_{x\in X} \text{len} \;h(x, \cdot)\]


\[\mathcal{I}(A,B) = \inf_{h} \max_{x\in X} \text{len} \;h(x, \cdot)\]
where $h$ satisfies:\\
$h : M\times I\rightarrow M$,
$h(\cdot,t) \;\text{homeomorphism}$,
$h(x,0) = x\;\forall\; x\in X$, 
$h(A,1) = B$



\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input! I ended up pulling the conditions out afterwards as you suggested. It's much more readable this way. (Before I was trying to define it as given in a paper I was citing).